# Drupal 7 Module to Set image src to a URL

Tags: 7, media, uri, entities

I am trying to do something pretty basic but I just cannot find the right module.

All I want to do is have a field type or widget that I can use in a content type that will set the image tag's src property to a URL without actually adding the file to Drupal.  The images for our site are located in a database and are accessible via a URL.

I tried the Media module but that adds the file to the Drupal images folder.

There's got to be a module for this.  Anyone know the right one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [Remote File Source](https://drupal.org/project/remote_file_source).

> Remote File Source allows you to add a file from a remote server to a filefield without transferring it locally.

Comment: Do you remember if there is an image display for [Link](https://drupal.org/project/link) module? I was sure I have seen it, but it might have been a custom solution.

Comment: @Mołot Do you mean [Image Link Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter)?

Comment: No, I'm sure I have seen link field formatted to display linked image instead of providing link to it. Seems exactly what OP wants, but I can't find it now. But it was in d6. Image Link Formatter uses uploaded images as illustration for links, so not good here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Clive.  I installed Remote File Source and its dependent modules but it doesn't seem to do what I need.  When I view that node I do not see an image--only a URL is displayed.  I can't believe I am the only person who uses external sources for images.  It's almost as if I will need to go back and change the images src param for every image the content managers add to the site.

Comment: Actually this did work.  I just needed to expand FILE SOURCES when defining the field and I found "Remote File" there.

Answer (score 2):

While media could definitely be extended to support the use-case, and there could already be such a module, there's a more specific option:

> [Imagecache External](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_external) is a utility module to allow you to use imagecache(D6) / Image Styles (D7) with external images.

Comment: Thanks Letharion.  Imagecache seems overly complex for what I am trying to achieve.  The end result of adding content to that image field simply needs to be that the image tag has a src param with a URL in it instead of a path to a local image.